# npm run dev permission denied

Tags: linux, npm, permissions

I have multiple sites on one server, however when I run `npm run dev`, which is an alias for `npm run development`, on a particulair one it gives a `permission denied` error on the root `/tmp/developmentblabla.sh` folder. When I run the command from other sites I don't have this issue, when I directly run `npm run development` I dont have this issue and when I run `npx mix` (which is called) I don't have this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX (Atleast MacOS, from my experience) don't like you changing things in root without running them as administrator.

Did you try sudo?
`sudo npm run dev`

[More information about sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is an option indeed but doesn't solve the real porblem which is that I only run into this error when running only this comment and only when running it from this folder on the server.